# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFragmentManager' of undefined

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, fragmentmanager, supportfragmentmanager

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFragmentManager' of undefined. This error is popping when I run my nativescript angular application.
It says something wrong in my account.component.ts.
Why this error is occurs and how to fix this issue?

[image: Click here to see error image]

Give any solution for this issue.

ts file:

```js
ngOnInit(){

    if (isAndroid) {
            
            
             const dialogFragment = application.android.foregroundActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
            
            if (dialogFragment) {
                utils.ad.dismissSoftInput(dialogFragment.getDialog().getCurrentFocus());
            } else {
                utils.ad.dismissSoftInput();
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: Please share relavant code.

Answer (score 0):

Is seems your problem is discussed here:
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5307